# Asp.net mvc-5 Scaffolding template wrongly mapped a Parent entity

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-mvc-scaffolding

I have an sql server database, which contains a table named “Technology” , which acts as a parent to many child tables such as Servers, VM, Switch, firewall, etc. The technology Entity class is as follow:-

```
public partial class Technology
    {
        public Technology()
        {
            this.ITServers = new HashSet<ITServer>();
            this.ITSwitchPorts = new HashSet<ITSwitchPort>();
            this.TechnologyAudits = new HashSet<TechnologyAudit>();
            this.TechnologyIPs = new HashSet<TechnologyIP>();
        }

        public int TechnologyID { get; set; }
        public string Tag { get; set; }
        public bool IsDeleted { get; set; }
        public byte[] timestamp { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> TypeID { get; set; }
        public Nullable<System.DateTime> StartDate { get; set; }
        public Nullable<long> IT360ID { get; set; }
        public bool IsCompleted { get; set; }
        public Nullable<long> PartialTag { get; set; }
        public bool IsManaged { get; set; }

        public virtual ITFirewall ITFirewall { get; set; }
        public virtual ITRack ITRack { get; set; }
        public virtual ITRouter ITRouter { get; set; }
        public virtual ITServer ITServer { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<ITServer> ITServers { get; set; }
        public virtual ITStorageDevice ITStorageDevice { get; set; }
        public virtual ITSwitch ITSwitch { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<ITSwitchPort> ITSwitchPorts { get; set; }
        public virtual TechnologyType TechnologyType { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<TechnologyAudit> TechnologyAudits { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<TechnologyIP> TechnologyIPs { get; set; }
        public virtual ITConsoleServer ITConsoleServer { get; set; }
        public virtual ITVirtualMachine ITVirtualMachine { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Now when I created a new controller for the Technology entity inside my asp.net mvc5 using the scaffolding template (MVC 5 with view using EF), the create action method will be as follow:-

```
 public ActionResult Create()
        {
            ViewBag.TechnologyID = new SelectList(db.ITFirewalls, "FirewallID", "Comment");
            ViewBag.TechnologyID = new SelectList(db.ITRacks, "ITRackID", "ITRackID");
            ViewBag.TechnologyID = new SelectList(db.ITRouters, "RouterID", "Description");
            ViewBag.TechnologyID = new SelectList(db.ITServers, "ITServerID", "ILOIP");
            ViewBag.TechnologyID = new SelectList(db.ITStorageDevices, "ITStorageDeviceID", "Comment");
            ViewBag.TechnologyID = new SelectList(db.ITSwitches, "SwitchID", "Spec");
            ViewBag.TypeID = new SelectList(db.TechnologyTypes, "AssetTypeID", "Name");
            ViewBag.TechnologyID = new SelectList(db.ITConsoleServers, "ConsoleServerID", "IPIn");
            ViewBag.TechnologyID = new SelectList(db.ITVirtualMachines, "ITVirtualMachineID", "Comment");
            return View();
        }
```

Where the scaffolding template have added multiple falsify viewbags for all the child records, and it did not use them inside the create view which looks as follow:-

```
@model WebApplication6.Models.Technology

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Create";
}

<h2>Create</h2>


@using (Html.BeginForm()) 
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <h4>Technology</h4>
        <hr />
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Tag, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Tag)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Tag)
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.IsDeleted, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.IsDeleted)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.IsDeleted)
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.TypeID, "TypeID", new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.DropDownList("TypeID", String.Empty)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.TypeID)
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.StartDate, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.StartDate)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.StartDate)
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.IT360ID, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.IT360ID)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.IT360ID)
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.IsCompleted, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.IsCompleted)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.IsCompleted)
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.PartialTag, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.PartialTag)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.PartialTag)
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.IsManaged, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.IsManaged)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.IsManaged)
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>
```

While when I try adding the same controller inside an asp.net mv4 the create action method looks as follow, which is more accurate:-

```
public ActionResult Create()
    {
        return View();
    }
```

So can anyone advice what is the problem in the scaffolding template inside an asp.net mvc5 , and why It have generated wrong viewbags for all the child entities?

one thing i should mention is that the PK for the child table(such as ITServer,ITFirewall, etc) is also the FK for the TechnologyID which is the PK for the Technology table,, could this have caused the problem ? for example inside the ITServer table the ITServerID acts as the PK for the ITServer table, and it is also the FK for the Technology.TechnologyID ..
Thanks

Comment: This could just be a bug, file it on connect.microsoft.com